# How can I delete the rownames which contain specific text in R?

Tags: r, r-rownames

I would like to remove the rownames ONLY of the rows which contain "Apple_"

```
df <- data.frame('fruit'=c("Apple_1", "Apple_2", "Apple_3", "Pear_1", "Pear_2", "Pear_3"),
                'color'=c("Red", "Red", "Green","Green","Green","Green"))
df<- column_to_rownames(df, var="fruit")
```

None of these work because I belive there aren't any rows called just "Apple"

```
row.names.remove <- c("Apple")
df[!(row.names(df) %in% row.names.remove), ]
df2<- length(which(grepl("Apple", rownames(df))))

df3<- df[row.names(df) != "Apple", , drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` with `-`

```
df[-grep('Apple', row.names(df)),, drop = FALSE]
```

Or `invert = TRUE`

```
df[grep('Apple', row.names(df), invert = TRUE),, drop = FALSE]
```

---

With `data.frame`, the rownames and column names attributes cannot be empty.  An option is to convert it to numeric index

```
i1 <- grep('Apple', row.names(df))
row.names(df)[i1] <- seq_along(i1)
```

---

Or convert to a `matrix` and then change those row names to blank (`""`)

```
m1 <- as.matrix(df)
row.names(m1)[i1] <- ""
```

as `matrix` allows duplicated rownames while `data.frame` doesn't.  It  is also possible to completely remove the rowname attribute, but it has to be across the whole object

Comment: But that deletes the full row, I'd like to keep the rows with no name for those containing "Apple"

Comment: @Ecg You meant to set the row names of that numbers ?

Comment: somethin like ```rownames(data) <- c()``` for those which rowname contains Apple?

Comment: @Ecg In the example you have suffix 1, 2, 3 for Apple, do you want 1 , 2, 3 because in `data.frame`, there needs to be row name

Comment: The thing is that in my datset I will only show a selected number of rownames, so Thought deleting all the rest of unwanted rownames to plot "" for them, and the name for the ones I want. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Ecg you could convert to `matrix` and matrix doesn't have any issue in removing the row nae attribute

Comment: @Ecg can you please check the updated solution.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks! What is the main difference between rownames for a dataframe and a matrix then?

Comment: @Ecg Difference is that if you do `row.names(m1) <- NULL`, it removes the rownames i.e. `dimnames(m1)` for rownames is `NULL`.  The same for `row.names(df) <- NULL` resets to sequence of rows i..e 1 to 6.

Comment: @Ecg There are certain rules/features for different class and it is not good to violate those